# Cannot access value from ngOnChanges SimpleChanges

Tags: angular

I'm trying to access data from an input to a component, and using ngOnChanges to do so, but VS code complains that the input I'm trying to grab isn't a property of the SimpleChanges object, and thus doesn't compile. What am I doing wrong here?

```
@Input('filters') filtersInput;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes);
    this.filters = changes.filtersInput.currentValue;
}
```

I get that filtersInput isn't a part of SimpleChanges, but as that's the class, it makes sense?

Comment: so whats there in `console.log(changes);` ?

Comment: It had a property called filtersInput, but Harry had the response below. I don't understand the compilation process yet :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was just a compilation-time error because the interface of `SimpleChanges` doesn't have `filtersInput` property explicitly:

```
export interface SimpleChanges {
    [propName: string]: SimpleChange;
}
```

You will have to get the value by using indexer instead:

```
this.filters = changes["filtersInput"].currentValue;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, and thanks for the explanation. if I understand properly, because the interface doesn't have the property explicitly, like you mentioned, using it as a property is not allowed, but treating it as an index (which my understanding is that that's improper in JS) is allowed? Feels like a strange breaking of convention for behavior, but maybe I'm not thinking about it properly.

Comment: @RhoVisions Indexer is the way to make it more generic for everybody to use, as interface/class definition is static, but your needs change all the time. If you feel uncomfy to use indexer, you'll need to create a subclass of `SimpleChanges` for every single occasion.

Comment: I don't mind using the index method, I just want to make sure I understand what's going on and why. Thanks.

Comment: The reason is all class definitions are static. The Angular team cannot just make every single definition for all components out there in the world (for example, they cannot foresee you using a field called `filtersInput` so cannot define it as a property in the `SimpleChanges`interface).